# Replacement only between begin{document} and \end{document}

Tags: livecode, livecoding

I have got some of the code from the stack-overflow and it's working, But while changing that code into my requirement(Replacement only between begin{document} and \end{document}) it's not working

this is the code i got

```
put wordOffset("begin{document}",fld "MytextField") into tBegin
put wordOffset("end{document}",fld "MytextField") into tEnd
put replaceText(word tBegin to tEnd of fld "MytextField","bad","good") into word tBegin to tEnd of fld "MytextField"
```

I am using the following code. How i convert above code to my requirement.

```
  on mouseUp 
       put the htmlText of field "MytextField" into myHtml 
       set the caseSensitive to true 
       put the field SRText into myArrayToBe 
       split myArrayToBe by CR 
       put the number of lines of (the keys of myArrayToBe) into myArraylength
       repeat with i = 1 to myArraylength 
          put  myArrayToBe[i] into y
          split y by colon
          put y[1] into searchStr
          put y[2] into replaceStr
          if searchStr is empty then
             put the  0 into m
          else 
          replace searchStr with  "<strike><font bgcolor=" & quote & "yellow" & quote & ">" & searchStr & "</font></strike><font bgcolor=" & quote & "green" & quote & ">" & replaceStr & "</font>" in myHtml
        end if
     end repeat 
     set the htmlText of fld "MytextField" to myHtml 
      end mouseUP
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now I think I understand your problem, try this...

```
on mouseUp 
   put the htmlText of field "MytextField" into myHtml

   ## First we need to break up myHTML into 3 parts so we can edit the "Document" part...
   -- Find the document "begin" marker and put it's position into the tBegin variable
   put wordOffset("begin{document}",myHtml) into tBegin

   -- Find the document "end" marker and put it's position into the tEnd variable
   put wordOffset("end{document}",myHtml) into tEnd 

   put word 1 to tBegin of myHtml into tHeader -- Part 1
   put word (tBegin +1) to (tEnd -1) of myHtml into tDocument -- Part 2 = the Document to change
   put word tEnd to -1 of myHtml into tFooter -- Part 3

   set the caseSensitive to true 
   put field "SRText" into myArrayToBe 
   split myArrayToBe by CR 
   put the number of lines of (the keys of myArrayToBe) into myArraylength
   repeat with i = 1 to myArraylength 
      put  myArrayToBe[i] into y
      split y by colon
      put y[1] into searchStr
      put y[2] into replaceStr
      if searchStr is empty then
         put the  0 into m
      else 
         replace searchStr with  "<strike><font bgcolor=" & quote & "yellow" & quote & ">" & searchStr & "</font></strike><font bgcolor=" & quote & "green" & quote & ">" & replaceStr & "</font>" in tDocument
      end if
   end repeat 

   ## Now we can rebuild the htmlText from the 3 parts and put it back in to the field...
   set the htmlText of fld "MytextField" to tHeader && tDocument && tFooter
end mouseUp
```